# Advantage of using $injector vs explicit DI declaration AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Just wondering if there's difference between:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('myctrl', ['$scope', 'customService',
     function($scope, customService) {
         // use customService
     }
]);
```

and using $injector

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('myctrl', ['$scope', '$injector',
     function($scope, $injector) {
         // get customService via injector and use it
         $injector.get('customService');
     }
]);
```

Sometimes I need to inject quite a few dependencies and my parameter list ends up to be lengthy. That's why I'm thinking the latter approach may be better for my scenario.

Does the difference affect testing or minification or any other reason?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. Look at [John Papa's Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#style-y091). You will do the injection before the controller function.

```
/* recommended */
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('Dashboard', Dashboard);

Dashboard.$inject = ['$location', '$routeParams', 'common', 'dataservice'];

function Dashboard($location, $routeParams, common, dataservice) {
}
```

Comment: This is only useful to tackle minification issues. This does not provide an answer for the OP's question

Answer (score 1):

Basically there is not much different, until you first encounter your **circular dependency** error while loading your module.

Simple [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seyenaz/hgyshghu/) that demonstrates circular dependency.

**Code (from fiddle):**

```
angular.module('app', [])
.service('serviceA', function (serviceB) {
    return {};
})
.service('serviceB', function (serviceA) {
    return {};
})
.controller('myCtrl', function (serviceA, serviceB) {
});
```

Using `$injector` helps prevent that scenario because when you use it inside the Controller/Factory/Service/etc instead of injecting the first way, you are delaying the dependency and therefore solving the problem.

And a simple [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seyenaz/hgyshghu/1/) that demonstrates how that problem is solved.

**Code (from fiddle):**

```
angular.module('app', [])
.service('serviceA', function (serviceB) {

    return {
        test: "it works!"
    };
})
.service('serviceB', function ($injector) {


    return {
        test: function() {
            var serviceA = $injector.get("serviceA");   

            return serviceA.test;
        }
    };
})
.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, serviceA, serviceB) { 
    $scope.test = serviceB.test();
});
```